# Can't get colorbox js to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, colorbox

I'm having trouble integrating colorbox.js into a site I've been given to work on as I can't get it to show anything (although I want it to show a video). Can anyone look at my code and tell me what I've done?

**HTML**

```
<div id="bl_hp_quickLinkBoxLeftThree">
    <a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Open Sesame!</a>
</div><!-- #bl_hp_quickLinkBoxLeftThree -->
<div id="bl_hp_quickLinkBoxRightThree">
    <p>This is some content</p>
</div><!-- #bl_hp_quickLinkBoxRightThree -->
<img src="./images/quicklinks/verso.png" />

<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
        <video controls="controls" poster="/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.jpg" style="width:100%" title="1280">
            <source src="/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.m4v" type="video/mp4" /><source src="/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <source src="/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.ogv" type="video/ogg" /><source src="/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.mp4" />
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/videos/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;">
                <param name="movie" value="/videos/flashfox.swf" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;poster=/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.jpg&amp;src=Company_video_EN_VERSION.m4v" />
                <embed src="/videos/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;"  flashVars="controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;poster=/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.jpg&amp;src=Company_video_EN_VERSION.m4v"   allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
                <img alt="Company video EN VERSION" src="/videos/Company_video_EN_VERSION.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;" width="100%" title="Video playback is not supported by your browser" />
            </object>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript** (Obviously I have loaded the JQuery script followed by the colorbox script)

```
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake made because it was a late coding session, I just needed to wrap it in an onload, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
});
```